# Performance issue with DATEADD function

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, dateadd

This is my actual select query,

```
SELECT b.CaseNumber as CaseNumber,b.DebtorNr ,b.ActionDate,DATEADD(MONTH,-12,b.ActionDate) one_month,a.Registerdate --COALESCE(count(A.historynr),0) as DebtorActivity  
                from rr..r_basic_info b 
                join rr..activities_VW as A on b.DebtorNr=a.Debtornr
                where 
                    B.Debtornr = A.Debtornr 
                    --and a.Registerdate<=b.ActionDate --this condition works
                    and a.registerdate >= DATEADD(month,-12,getdate()) --i have a problem with this condition and causing huge time consumption
```

I have a view defined here is activities_VW

```
select H.NR as historynr,o.debtornr as Debtornr, O.NR as ordernr, h.Actmenunr as Actmenunr,h.AGREEMENT as AgreementCode, h.Registerdate as Registerdate
```

from abc..history h  join abc..orders o on o.NR=h.ORDERNR

and my execution plan is like 
[image]

One more information for all rows b.actionDate column has identical value like '2015-04-11 08:37:44.037'.
I have checked with all date format but nothing wrong found.
For another case, I have different value for different rows in b.actionDate column and it is working fine for that case.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the execution plan that gets generated?

Comment: Is this going to be a common query in exactly this form? If so, you might want to consider adding (and indexing) a [Computed Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) that is `DATEADD(MONTH, - 6, a.joining_date)`

Comment: you have a functin over a.joiningdate, so it's probably scanning the assignment table in a loop

Comment: no i don't have any function or index on a.joining_date column

Comment: Just curious, how many rows are in the tables?  whenever you use a function in a `where/join` criteria the function needs to be performed on every row in the table to assert.  Unless there are a huge number of rows in the table however, i wouldn't think it would be ***that*** impactful.

Comment: Try putting an index on joining_date and id in table assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong in my understanding so take it only as a possibility - when using a function within a join criteria and/or where clause, in order to determine if data meets the criteria, it must be checked against every row in the table.

Think about your first part `WHERE e.DATE <= a.joining_date` - you can simply look directly at rows that are less than the `e.DATE`.

For your second part `AND e.DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 6, a.joining_date)` - there is no column the is "joining date minus 6 months", so to determine if `e.Date` is greater than it, you would need to perform that calculation on every instance of `a.joining_date` in the table.

Remember that where clause information is *not necessarily evaluated* in the order is it written down in the query - so the rows you would think are eliminated by the first part of your `where` are not necessarily eliminated by it.  So as one of the comments suggested, using a computed/persisted column on the `DATEADD(MONTH, - 6, a.joining_date)` would probably work well.

Comment: actually DATEADD(MONTH, - 6, a.joining_date) works fine if a.joining_date column contains different values but when it contains values that contains identical value for all rows then it got stuck

Answer (score 0):

This is my actual select query,

```
SELECT b.CaseNumber as CaseNumber,b.DebtorNr ,b.ActionDate,DATEADD(MONTH,-12,b.ActionDate) one_month,a.Registerdate --COALESCE(count(A.historynr),0) as DebtorActivity  
                from rr..r_basic_info b 
                join rr..activities_VW as A on b.DebtorNr=a.Debtornr
                where 
                    B.Debtornr = A.Debtornr 
                    --and a.Registerdate<=b.ActionDate --this condition works
                    and a.registerdate >= DATEADD(month,-12,getdate()) --i have a problem with this condition and causing huge time consumption
```

I have a view defined here is activities_VW

```
select H.NR as historynr,o.debtornr as Debtornr, O.NR as ordernr, h.Actmenunr as Actmenunr,h.AGREEMENT as AgreementCode, h.Registerdate as Registerdate
```

from abc..history h  join abc..orders o on o.NR=h.ORDERNR

and my execution plan is like 
[image]

One more information for all rows b.actionDate column has identical value like '2015-04-11 08:37:44.037'.
I have checked with all date format but nothing wrong found.
For another case, I have different value for different rows in b.actionDate column and it is working fine for that case.

Thanks

Comment: I have about 50000 rows in basic_info table